# multiple X11 forwards over ssh?

Tags: ssh, xorg

I have two servers (lets say A and B). In order to ssh into A, I need to ssh into B first, and then into A. I want to run some GUI applications on A, so I am looking to forward X11 twice over ssh.

However when I run an application from A I get:

```
Error: no display specified
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you're adding the `-Y` flag, and that X11 forwarding is enabled in both servers' ssh config files in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: yes and yes ...

Answer (score 0):

would the following work for you?

```
export DISPLAY=serverB:0
```

Comment: well, I gave export DISPLAY:IPAddressOfB:0 (didn't work)